# ,Chain react-spring animations on hover

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I'm trying to do a simple multi-step animation on `react-spring`: rotating an icon that goes to `10deg`, then `-10deg`, and go back to `0deg`. This animation will execute when the user hovers the icon.

The following snippet illustrates an animation with just the 1st step:

```js
const [isBooped, setBooped] = useState(false);

const style = useSpring({
  rotate: isBooped ? 10 : 0,
  config: config.wobbly,
});

const onMouseEnter = useCallback(() => setBooped(true), []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!isBooped) {
    return;
  }

  const timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
    setBooped(false);
  }, 250);

  return () => {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  };
}, [isBooped]);

return (
  <Button onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}>
    <Icon style={style} />
  </Button>
);
```

I understand that `to` accepts an array to chain multiple animations like so:

```js
to: [{ rotate: 10 }, { rotate: -10 }, { rotate: 0 }],
```

...but I do not know how to handle this along with the `isBooped` state.

Here's a sandbox with the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-test-o8fwm?file=/src/Notifications.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good opportunity to use the [imperative API](https://react-spring.io/common/imperatives-and-refs#api-methods) react-spring has to offer.

You can also cancel the animation mid flow if you want it to stop animating when someone is not hovering over the icon, or maybe it should just reset itself back to `0` cutting the animation short (this is commented out in the example provided below).

By passing a function to the `useSpring` hook you get an array where the first item is your styles and the second is the API. You can then use an effect to trigger the async animation to begin running. Here's your codesandbox modified to demonstrate this: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-test-forked-ildtb?file=/src/Notifications.js

Comment: thanks. I was aware of the imperative API but not on passing the rotation changes on `start`. This definitely solves it.